# React Testing Library Not Parsing JSON

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a TextArea component that takes JSON `{"someKey": "someValue"}`. When I inspect the dom, `{"someKey": "someValue"}` shows up just fine in the inspector.

However, when I try react testing library, RTL thinks the TextArea seems to contain `"[object Object]"` which isn't JSON parseable.

Any insight into

1. Why RTL is interpreting this json as `"[object Object]"`
2. How I can test it? I'd like to assert the value I typed in is there

Comment: Can you include some of your code? Likely you're not marshaling the input properly.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)